# ejercicio programación estructurada en python

Tags: python

```py
suma = 0
m = 0
max = 0

cargar = True
while cargar:
    grado =  int(input("Ingrese el grado o -1 si desea salir :"))
    if grado ==-1:     
      cargar = False
    else :
      carrera = input("Ingrese una carrera : ")
      cargar1 = True

      while grado !=-1 and cargar1 == True:
         materias = input("Ingrese las materias : ") 
         if  materias =="":  

            cargar1= False
         else: 
          notas = int(input("Ingrese la nota: "))
          m = m +1
          suma = suma + notas
          promedio = suma/m
      print(promedio)
      if promedio>max :
                max = promedio
print(max)
```

En este ejercicio tengo que  ingresar por teclado el grado del curso y cargar las materias con sus respectivas notas, y devolver el grado que tiene el mayor promedio y el promedio.
No puedo calcularlo.

Comment: El promedio no puedes calcularlo hasta que tengas todas las notas. La línea `promedio=suma/m` debería estar fuera del `while` anidado. Por otro lado, tu actualización de la variable `max`  servirá para obtener al final cuál fue el promedio mayor, pero no a qué grado pertenece. Necesitarás además otra variable `grado_max` que tome el valor del grado cuando `promedio>max`.

Comment: La primera vez que cargo las notas del primer alumno, me da correcto su promedio , pero al cargar las del segundo alumno me suma el promedio de los dos.

Comment: Ah, claro. Tienes que volver a poner a 0 la `suma` y `m ` cada vez que cambias de grado. Es decir, en vez de inicializarlas al principio del programa, hazlo dentro del bucle `while cargar`, al principio del mismo.